# How to add request filters in Play framework?

Tags: java, logging, playframework

I would like to show in my logs, the time that could takes every request or action..

I added this class to my controller but nothing happen in my log!!!!
what should i do to show request time in my log please ?

thank you in advance.
[Reference of Class](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters)

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.*;

public class LoggingFilter extends Filter {

    @Inject
    public LoggingFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
            Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,
            Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return nextFilter.apply(requestHeader).thenApply(result -> {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long requestTime = endTime - startTime;

            Logger.info("{} {} took {}ms and returned {}",
                requestHeader.method(), requestHeader.uri(), requestTime, result.status());

            return result.withHeader("Request-Time", "" + requestTime);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add your filter to the filter chain? See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters#Using-filters

Comment: Hell Roman,
what do you mean by filter chain ?
do i have to add this class in the controller next to the first one ?

Comment: Have you configured the filters in your config? Please follow the link provided by @Roman which shows the thing that assembles all your filters and is configured. This is the chain.

Comment: Hi,The ecplications provided by the teams play framework are a bit advanced for me and surpass my skills:

Here are the steps I have taken:

1- I added a new class in my controller and I named it: LoggingFilter.java
2- I add this in application.conf: play.http.filters = com.LoggingFilter

My log still does not show request time for every action or page request!
Please excuse me for my weak skills.

Comment: Does someone has an idea please?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your filter chain - see [this section of documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters#Using-filters) for the official guide.

```
import filters.LoggingFilter;
import play.http.DefaultHttpFilters;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {
  @Inject
  public Filters(LoggingFilter logging) {
    super(logging);
  }
}
```

If your `Filters` class is in the root package, you don't need to change anything in your `application.conf`.  For the standard Play package structure, the root package is at the same level as `controllers` and `views`, and the `Filters` class itself will not have `package` as the first line of the source file.

```
+- controllers
| \ App.java
+- filters
| \ LoggingFilter.java
- Filters.java
```

If you have it somewhere else, say, `com.example.filters`, you need to declare it in `application.conf`.

```
play.http.filters=com.example.Filters
```

Comment: Hello steve,
What do you mean by root package ? did you mean : 
Controllers ?
another question if i may please, do i have only to add your action instead of mine in the controllers.java ? thank you so much for help

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the root package.  I'm not sure what you mean by controllers.java.

Comment: Oh ok, it is a folder named filters and its location is : /app/filters
I am really a fool girl hahaha ok im gona try that and see if application.log is going to display time by action or request
i will tell you ;) really thanks and excuses for my little knowledge on JAVA

Comment: The root package is `/app/`, not `/app/filters`.  `/app/filters` is a package to  keep your custom filters in.

Comment: I tried but no success: i got this error :
http://imgur.com/a/D2mVn
any idea please!!!
steps to reproduce : 
1- I add a class named : Filters.java in the root (/app)
2- I filled this class with your content 
=> Error

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: Hi Steve, I am really thankful coz of your returns...here is the version i am using in plugins.sbt :
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")

Comment: Create a new Play Java project using `activator new someName`, selecting the Play Java template when asked, and you'll have a project that contains filters.  This is the easiest way for you to get a working example.

Comment: I had never worked with ACTIVATOR before...I just work with SBT:  (sbt clean run) that's all, if you have an example using filters could u plz zip it and send it in google drive or whatever....i really need this before delivering my customer an app

Comment: This app uses filters: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/tree/master/test-app-filters

Comment: It turns out that the only example present on GITHUB and on the net concerning the filters tells me: I will never works if it is you HANNAH lol
Http://imgur.com/a/tenvM